# SQL or SAS function to impute categorical variables based on other similar records

Tags: sql-server, sas

I have a dataset that looks similar to what I've pasted below. What I need to do is fill in all of the missing values in the Group column based on the values in the group_no column. For example, if Group_no is 1, then all of the values for Group should be "Crops."

I've tried a few things, most recently a CASE WHEN  statement, which I thought was going to work, but flopped. I tried an if/else, but there are 200k records, and 8000 different groups, and I am not sure how to go about this without updating each record one by one. I've been spinning my wheels with this one for a while, and I think that a fresh set of eyes might help.

When I run the code below, the error I get is

> ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row.

I am doing this in SAS, using Proc SQL, so if you have a more simple approach using a Data step, then that is welcome as well.

```
proc sql;
select 
a.ID
, a.Group
, a.Industry
, a.Group_no
,CASE WHEN a.Group IN (' ') THEN (select first(b.group) from mydata as b where first(a.Group_no) = first(b.Group_no)) END AS group_desc2
from mydata as a;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Those look like NAICS/Industry codes, are you trying to make a NAICS lookup table? If so, those exist in a few places that you can grab them from.

Comment: They are, but I have them in a very old SOR and there are a bunch that are apparently no longer in use that are still assigned in our SOR so I am using the group number to fill in the blanks and get a better understanding of the customer demographic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL**

The correlated sub-query causes the `ERROR:` because it has multiple rows:

```
, CASE 
    WHEN a.Group IN (' ') 
    THEN (select first(b.group) from mydata as b where first(a.Group_no) = first(b.Group_no)) 
  END AS group_desc2
```

Change the sub-query to one that returns a single row.  Something like:

```
, case 
    when not missing(group) then group
    else (select min(group) from have as inner where inner.group_no = outer.group_no)
  end
  as group
```

Important SAS SQL reminders:

- Missing values are considered to be the NULL value.
- Aggregate functions operate only on non NULL values.
- An empty correlated sub-query (i.e. no rows) is coerced to a null value when being assigned in the outer scope.

**Data Concerns**

- Per @Reeza it may be better to utilize industry standard lookup tables rather than 'self-found' lookup values.
- Regarding self-found,

  - What should happen when the `group` value is missing from **all** rows of a `GROUP_NO` group?
  - What should happen when the 'group' has multiple values with-in a `GROUP_NO` group ?

**DATA Step**

Per @Stu-Sztukowski

- way #1 will not appear to do anything, if at `first.group_no` the `group` value is missing (i.e. `' '`).
- way #2 can cause an `ERROR: This range is repeated...` when multiple `group` values occur within `group_no`.

**DATA Step - Way #3**

Use a DOW loop to capture first non-missing `group` value and a subsequent serial loop to apply as necessary.

```
data want(drop=_:);
  length _first_group $20.;

  * data is pre-sorted by `group_no`;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.group_no);
    set have;
    by group_no;
    if missing(_first_group) then
      _first_group = group;
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if missing (group) then group=_first_group;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Fortunately, i went through and manually made sure the first record within each group has a listing, so when I sort by ID, record 100 for example would be 100 CROPS CROPS 1, so this isn't an exact replica of my dataset, but it does solve for the possibility of not having a proper description within the first record of each group. I'll end up with some fluffernutter in the Industry column, but since I can't find that info, the group will be sufficient for the pieces of missing data (which is about 10% of the overall dataset).

Comment: Also regarding the data concerns,  I sourced most of these values from an industry table, and joined to the company dataset since we only store the ID/SIC code. The resulting missing values are apparently no longer in circulation. I checked a couple of industry tables and went with the most robust option. Regarding self-found, all records have a group_no as this is derived from ID, but if there isnt a value for Group, then leave as blank for now. And 2, Group:Group_no is a 1:1 relationship, as is ID:Industry. As long as I can impute most of the nulls for group, I'll be good to go.

Comment: Your solution with a Data Step #3 worked. Thank you! As you had mentioned with the other solutions provided, #1 didn't do anything, and #2, for some reason, replaced group with the value for group_no in many cases. Glad I used a temporary dataset and wasn't overwriting my original. Since the format for Group in your solution was limited to 20 characters, it also provided me with a simple way to identify and label the imputed values as such. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

**Way 1.**

Sort it by `group_no` `descending group` and fill-in missing values with the correct group value.

For each group number, store the name of the group in a temporary variable we create named `_group` that carries until the next group number. `_group` will always hold the name of the current group number and let you fill it in as needed. Since we've sorted the dataset by `descending group`, a valid group name will always be the first observation within the group number (unless they are all missing).

```
proc sort data=have;
    by group_no descending group;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by group_no descending group;
    retain _group;

    if(first.group_no) then group = _group;

    if(missing(group)) then group = _group;

    drop _group;
run;
```

**Way 2.**

Create a format of all non-missing group numbers/group names

This will use a format to associate a group number with a group name. You can use SQL to create a format dataset specifically for reading into `proc format`. The SQL statement below selects all distinct non-missing group numbers and gives you a format dataset of non-missing group numbers and group names. This is used to create a custom format named `$groupfmt.` This effectively acts as a lookup table.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table group_fmt as
        select distinct 
            group_no   as start
          , group_no   as end
          , group      as label
          , 'C'        as type
          , 'groupfmt' as fmtname
        from have
        where NOT missing(group)
        ;
quit;

proc format cntlin=group_fmt;
run;

data want;
    set have;

    if(missing(group)) then group = put(group_no, $groupfmt.);
run;
```

`put(group_no, $groupfmt.)` can also be used in a SQL query rather than a data step.

Comment: The _abc123_ notation in SAS is something that I haven't quite wrapped my head around yet. IIRC, it stores whatever you're assigning in memory and doesnt create a dataset? Either way, I'll take a closer look in the morning. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hmm... abc123 was supposed to have the underscores in front/back of it. I guess I haven't fully wrapped my head around stackoverflow formatting yet either.

Comment: In SAS, `_var_` can sometimes refer to automatic system generated variables that are dropped at the end of a data step. For example, `_n_` is always generated in every data step and counts the number of iterations within a data step  For temporary variables that I don't want later in subsequent datasets, I tend to prefix them with an underscore so they're easy to identify and drop later. This way I can use a statement such as `drop _:` to drop all temporary variables prefixed with `_`. I tend to do the same with temporary datasets as well. I updated the above to make it a little less confusing